# Defining angle in terms as a limit of ratios of volumes

Tags: geometry, angle

Let $(\vec{w})^{\varepsilon}$ denote an open ball of radius $\varepsilon$ centered at $\vec{w}$ . The choice of *open* balls over closed balls is arbitrary. Let $S$ denote a set that's constrained to be the union of an open set $T$ and its boundary.

Can you define the angle at a point $\vec{v}$ in a set $S$ embedded in $\mathbb{R}^n$ as a limit of the ratio of the volume of $S \cap (\vec{v})^\varepsilon$ and $(\vec{v})^\varepsilon$ as $\varepsilon$ approaches zero? Does this still work as a definition of angle in more exotic spaces than $\mathbb{R}^n$ with the norm $L^2$ ? *Since this is not the usual way we build a notion of angles, is there a specific way in which the limit-of-volumes definition is incoherent or less parsimonious than the standard one?*

I think the ordinary way of defining a notion of angle uses the inner product, $I(\vec{x}, \vec{y}) = \langle\vec{x}, \vec{y}\rangle$ , which gives you distance and angle in one fell swoop. My recollection is a bit hazy. At very least, the following equality (1) can be used to define the angle between two vectors as in (2):

$$ \cos(\theta) = \frac{\langle A,B \rangle}{\sqrt{\langle A, A \rangle \langle B, B \rangle}} \tag{1} $$

$$ \theta \stackrel{def}{=} \arccos\left( \frac{\langle A,B \rangle}{\sqrt{\langle A, A \rangle \langle B, B \rangle}} \right) \tag{2} $$

What I'm considering is the following:

$$ \frac{\theta}{2\pi} \stackrel{def}{=} \lim_{\varepsilon \to 0} \frac{\left| S \cap (\vec{v})^{\varepsilon} \right|}{\left| (\vec{v})^{\varepsilon} \right|} \tag{3} $$

In (3), $2\pi$ is just chosen to make the definition line up with radians in 2 dimensions. It probably makes sense to choose a different constant in other numbers of dimensions or just use $1$.

The intuition is that we're zooming in on one point and asking how much of our set $S = (T \cup \partial(T))$ is in a circle/sphere centered at $\vec{v}$ . Because $S$ cannot be *just* the boundary of a triangle, for instance, and has to include some points on either side of the boundary, we're always making a choice between exterior and interior angles.

This definition also generalizes to arbitrarily many dimensions. We can, for instance, ask what the "angle" is at the one of the points of a regular tetrahedron.

It also has the somewhat strange property that any point in the interior of $S$ has angle $2\pi$ and any point completely outside it has angle $0$ .

So anyway, this is probably a horrible way to define what an angle is and requires more machinery than just an inner product. Are there additional reasons why it's bad?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your definition is quite reasonable, cf. [steradian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Steradian).

You are basically defining the [density of a set at a point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lebesgue%27s_density_theorem).

I don't think you can generalize this approach to $L^2$ because it is not [locally compact](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Locally_compact_space), so the balls cannot have finite measure (you can pack an *infinite* number of balls of radius $\frac14$ inside a unit ball).